# model.evaluate() returns different value for same metric depending on if it is returned as the loss or as a metric

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I compiled and trained a model like so:

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=pixelwise_weighted_binary_crossentropy, metrics=[pixelwise_weighted_binary_crossentropy, dice_coef, dice_loss])
```

Now during evaluation I get different values for `loss_weighted_cross_entropy_value_1` and `weighted_cross_entropy_value_2`, when running:

```
(loss_weighted_cross_entropy_value_1, weighted_cross_entropy_value_2, dice_value, dice_loss_value) = model.evaluate(data_generator)
```

Here, `weighted_cross_entropy_value_2` returns the value I expect (same value as during training, when running on the validation dataset), but `loss_weighted_cross_entropy_value_1` seems to randomly fluctuate around that value, depending on batch-size.

If I had to wager a guess, it seems as if `loss_weighted_cross_entropy_value_1` is the value for only the last batch of the evaluation data. Whereas `weighted_cross_entropy_value_2` is the averaged value across all batches of the evaluation data.

Is this correct or is what is going on here?

---

**Edit**:

I now ran the evaluation on each batch individually by getting them from the generator first and feeding them to `model.evaluate(...)` as numpy arrays (see code below). Averaging over the batch-results of `loss_weighted_cross_entropy_val_1` and `weighted_cross_entropy_val_2` gives the same result in this case:

```
Averaged loss_weighted_cross_entropy_val_1 - per-sample pass: 0.08109399276593375; std: 0.005511607824946092
Averaged weighted_cross_entropy_val_2 - per-sample pass: 0.08109399271862848; std: 0.005511607193872294
```

I see this as further indication for my interpretation above.

Code:

```
nr_of_samples = len(data_generator)
result = nr_of_samples * [None]
loss_weighted_cross_entropy_val_1 = np.zeros(nr_of_samples)
weighted_cross_entropy_val_2 = np.zeros(nr_of_samples)
dice_val = np.zeros(nr_of_samples)
dice_loss_val = np.zeros(nr_of_samples)

for index, sample in enumerate(data_generator):
    image = sample[0]
    mask_weight = sample[1]
    (loss_weighted_cross_entropy_val_1[index], weighted_cross_entropy_val_2[index], dice_val[index], dice_loss_val[index]) = model.evaluate(image, mask_weight)
    print(f"Sample {index}/{nr_of_samples}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same function as the loss and metric, you will see minor difference in results usually due to `floating point precision errors`.

Please refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62174185/14290681), which explain in detail for this case.