# Why is the mse loss different to the mse metric when training a tensorflow 2.3 model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.x

I have written a custom model in tensorflow (using version 2.4 in python 3.9.5) so that I can implement my own custom loss function. I noticed that when using the mean squared error as the loss in my custom model (via the self.compute_loss method) and implementing this in the self.train_step, I get a different value for the mean squared error **metric** to that of the **loss**.

The shape of the input data is (1000, 18) and the output data is (1000, 1).

See the code below:

```py
def mse_func(y_true, y_pred):
    # if we don't call tf.reduce_mean we get loads of arrays as an output
    # mse = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred) 

    mse = tf.reduce_mean(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
    return mse


class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y_true = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            loss = self.compute_loss(y_true, y_pred)
        
        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y_true, y_pred)

        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value (to work
        # with tensorboard)
        metrics_dict = {
            'loss': loss,
        }
        metrics_dict.update({m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics})
        return metrics_dict

    def compute_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        mse = mse_func(y_true, y_pred)
        return mse
```

```
Epoch 1/10
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0053 - mean_squared_error: 0.0113
Epoch 2/10
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_squared_error: 0.0063
Epoch 3/10
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0018 - mean_squared_error: 0.0032
Epoch 4/10
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0024 - mean_squared_error: 0.0023
...
```

However when I pass the model's compute_loss method as the loss to the `model.compile()` call, and replace `loss = self.compute_loss(y_true, y_pred)` with `loss = self.compiled_loss(y_true, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)`, the values are equivalent (which is the expected behaviour):

```py
# when passing the 'mse' loss into the model.compile call it doesn't give us the same problem
# e.g. no problem with this code:
model = CustomModel(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(),
    metrics=['mean_squared_error'],
    loss = model.compute_loss
)
```

```
Epoch 1/10
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0119 - mean_squared_error: 0.0119
Epoch 2/10
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_squared_error: 0.0060
Epoch 3/10
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0040 - mean_squared_error: 0.0040
Epoch 4/10
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0021 - mean_squared_error: 0.0021
Epoch 5/10
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0019 - mean_squared_error: 0.0019
...
```

I'm not sure I understand what is going on under the hood. Is there something different going on when using a non-compiled loss in the train_step function that would cause the difference?

Comment: Hi @kbaker, In deep networks, using the same function as the loss and a metric yields distinct results. Generally, this is due to floating point precision problems. Please refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62174185/14290697) for more details. Thank you!